# scaffolding error in cakephp 1.3

Tags: cakephp-1.3

i've just started to work on cakephp i've just created the models and in the controller i just have 2 lines

```
class BlogController extends AppController{
var $name='BlogController';
var $scaffold;
}
```

i'm getting this error in the view

```
Undefined property:  BlogController::$primaryKey [CORE/cake/libs/controller/scaffold.php, line 182]
Undefined property:  BlogController::$displayField [CORE/cake/libs/controller/scaffold.php, line 183]
```

yes what could be the problem
thanx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figured it out in the name variable i added controller which is not requied and sorry for asking such a dumb question